# Export map from Google Earth

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, storage

I am trying to export a map from Google Earth to Cloud storage with Export.map.toCloudStorage:

```
Export.map.toCloudStorage({
    image: myMap.visualize(myMapVis),
    description: '123',
    bucket: 'bucket',
    path: '01',
    scale: 500
});
```

When the task is finished **not all tiles are exported**. If I zoom out to 0, then I see the whole layer, but when I zoom in a bit I only see some region. It feels like map reduce job that is producing a map was dropping results from some nodes. Does anyone had similar problem? Is it solvable?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify region, the current view in the code editor will be exported. In other words, set an argument 'region' which is a geometry you would like to export.

***region (Geometry.LinearRing|Geometry.Polygon|String, optional):***
A LinearRing, Polygon, or coordinates representing region to export. These may be specified as the Geometry objects or coordinates serialized as a string. If not specified, the region defaults to the viewport at the time of invocation.

Comment: Kuik, thank you very much for you reply! how can I set whole world as a region?

Comment: Zoom out, draw a polygon of the world and use that? However, I guess you will have to increase the scale drastically to make a runable computation.